# lxml module cannot be found

Tags: python, lxml

Download lxml-2.3.3.tar.gz

Extract it then run sudo python setup.py build under the folder

python selftest.py =>184 tests ok.

Extract lxml folder lxml-2.3.3\src\lxml to my python path

Running the application will cause error - Usage of the XML aspects requires lxml

Is that correct way to build and install?

Comment: Use easy_install(or pip): `easy_install lxml`.  It looks like you are on windows so easy_install should be in the scripts subdirectory of your python folder

Answer (score 2):

After building, you have to install using

```
python setup.py install
```

Simply copying the folder to python path will not work.

Or you can just use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and run

```
pip install lxml
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you can download the pre-built module from this [windows python lib site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml). Note that this is unofficial, but highly respected.